# Solving Inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

If there is an Inequality

$-x^2+2x+3>0 $On solving it we get

$x\in(-\infty, - 1)\cup(3,\infty)$ but if we multiply the eq by $- 1$ on solving we get $x\in(-1,3)$....why??

And what is considered to be correct?

Comment: when you multiplied by $-1$, did you remember to flip the sign?

Comment: When you multiply both sides of an inequality by a negative number, the inequality sign reverses direction.

Comment: x∈(−1,3) is the solution of x^2−2x−3<0 but not - x^2+2x+3>0!!!! –

Comment: Someone edited my question wrong

Comment: Read the edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you ought to know the graph of this quadratic equation. it opens downward, has a vertex at $(1, 4)$ which is a local max. the $x$ intercepts of $y = -x^2 + 2x + 3 = -(x-1)^2 + 4 = (1+x)(3 - x)$ are $x = -1$ and $x = 3$ so we have $$-x^2 + 2x + 3 > 0  \text{ on } -1 < x < 3.$$

Answer (score 0):

When you multiply the eq by -1, the direction of inequality will reversed. So $x\in (-1,3)$ is the solution of $x^2-2x-3\lt 0$.

Comment: x∈(−1,3) is the solution of x^2−2x−3<0 but not - x^2+2x+3>0!!!! –

Comment: Read the edited question

Answer (score 0):

Nope, if you multiply by -1, you get the same result. Don't forget that when you're multiplying by a negative number you must change > to < !

Try to see that as a parabola.

Comment: So x∈(−1,3) is the solution of x^2−2x−3<0 but not - x^2+2x+3>0!!!!

Comment: Read the edited question

Comment: You made a mistake, the solution of -x^2+2x+3>0 is x∈)-1,3(